# Is there a general results concerning what $E(X_1\mid X_1, X_2)$ equals?

Tags: probability

I believe that $E(X_1\mid X_1, X_2)$ equals $E(X_1\mid X_2)$ but am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_1$ is $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$-measurable, therefore $E[X_1\mid X_1,X_2]:=E[X_1\mid \sigma(X_1,X_2)]=X_1$

Comment: there is a typo above, no?

Comment: @DanielS. I don't see any in my post. Can you be more specific?

Comment: the expected value equals a random variable? $E[X_1|X_1,X_2] = X_1$ ? I think this needs an adjustment, no?

Comment: @DanielS. $E[X\mid Y]$ is not an expected value. It's the conditional expectation with respect to the variable $Y$.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the difference between expected value and conditional expectation?

Comment: @DanielS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition

Comment: in any case, in the left hand side of your expression you have $E(X_1|X_1,X_2)$ and in the right hand side you have something that does not depend on $X_2$? This is very strange for me ... you have only $X_1$ in the right hand side?!

Comment: @DanielS. $X_1$ depends on the random vector $(X_1,X_2)$.

Comment: this is very confusing to me -- $X_1$ depends on the random vector $(X_1,X_2)$?  wow, I've never seen this notation before, but I'm not used to formal probability theory. Maybe there would be an alternative way to express the equality above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106897/discussion-between-daniel-s-and-gae-s).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by $E(X_1 | X_1, X_2)$.

- Meaning 1: $E(X_1 | X_1, X_2) = E(X_1 | X_1=c, X_2=d)$, where $c$ and $d$ are constants. Then, $E(X_1)=c$
- Meaning 2: $E(X_1 | X_1, X_2)$ stands for the expectation of $X_1$ given $X_1$ and $X_2$ as random variables. This is a somewhat heavy notation, which actually is obtained from $$E(X_1 | X_1=c, X_2=d)$$ replacing $c$ and $d$ by random variables.  In that case,  $$E(X_1 | X_1=c, X_2=d)=E(X_1 | X_1=Y, X_2=Z)=E(X_1|X_2)=E(Y|Z)$$ by definition.

Check also

[Conditioning on function of random variable and random variable itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844912/conditioning-on-function-of-random-variable-and-random-variable-itself)